# How to make two <div>...</div> in the same row?

Tags: html

I mean, the two  tags have the same height.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this for all divs.

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: +1 display:inline isn't flexible enough and floats are messy!

Answer (score 9):

Simple: **use `<span>`s instead**.

`<div>` by default have `display: block`, meaning the next element will be on a new line.

You can change them to `display: inline` to get the behavior you want. But remember that an inline `<div>` is just a `<span>`.

Answer (score 2):

Float them with css:

```
float: left
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a div container and put inside all your divs.

```
.div_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

That easy!

Answer (score 1):

Make them float:

HTML

```
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS

```
.clear { clear: both; }
.container1, .container2 { float: left; }
```

You have to clear the float.. so use clear both :)

Answer (score 1):

Float messes up my page center alignment.  Here's what I got, I want to get 2 and 3 on the same row without losing the page centering.  Float doesn't work because when I resize the browser,it moves with it.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<style type="text/css">
.div1 {
   background: #faa;
   width: 500;
 }

.div2 {
  background: #ffc;
  width: 400;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.div3 {
  background: #cfc;
  width: 100;
  margin-left: 400px;

}


</style>
</head>

<html>
<body>
<center>

<div class="div1"> This is no 1</div>
<div class="div2"> This is no 2</div>
<div class="div3"> This is no 3</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```