# Put two divs in a row with php echo

Tags: php, html, class

I made one div where I put echo php, that are reading informations from database. I put one `<br>` to the end of php functions to separate informations for another customer. Now I want to put two divs in a row but I have `<br>` that won't let it. How to solve this?

Code:

```
<div class="divmobilni">
<div class="floatright"><img src="images/nokia-lumia-720.jpg" height="66px" width="50px" /></div>
Ime:<div class="imepozadina"><?php echo $row['Ime'];?></div><br />
Okrug:<?php echo $row['Okrug'];?>
<br />
Telefon:<?php echo $row['Telefon'];?>
</div>
<br />
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

And with this code it looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/bq6565c4b/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Can't you simply put another `div` before the `br`?

Comment: And what to enter into that div?

Comment: whatever you want to echo? Note that by default, `div` tags are block elements and so take up an entire row (unless you float them or change them to `inline` or `inline-block` via CSS). Are you sure it's the `br` that's causing the break?

Comment: @KevinPei With this code, divs are like this: http://postimg.org/image/bq6565c4b/
Now I want to put two divs in same row, not to be only one div in one row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make two <div>...</div> in the same row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340971/how-to-make-two-div-div-in-the-same-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two elements per row, I would encourage you to make use of a grid system such as Skeleton (http://getskeleton.com/)

It would be far more reliable and safe to use a proven framework such as **Skeleton** or **Bootstrap**

---

However, if you would like to DIY it, you would need to

1. Set the div's to either `inline-block` or `float:left/right` and set `width:50%` to each of them.
2. Remove the line breaks (`br`'s), as the elements will automatically break themselves.

Try the following CSS:

```
.divmobilni{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px; //remove any margins to prevent breaking at each element
    box-sizing:border-box; //allow paddings to not interfere with element width 
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Using a framework to align 2 elements on the same row ? Ain't that overkill ?

Comment: @sodawillow Is it overkill? Yes. That's why I recommended Skeleton over Bootstrap and didn't even mention Semantic or anything of the like. 

Why create your own classes though when you have bug-tested well-proven code that's out there for you to use? Also given OP was trying to align two boxes side by side, it would be reasonable to assume he would have similar situations with other elements as well.